# Is there anything like Assembly Binding Log Viewer on Windows Azure?

Tags: logging, azure

Is there anything like Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fusion Log Viewer) on Windows Azure? How can I watch log for assemblies which are using now on Windows Azure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can RDP to the instance, then you can use the fusion log viewer just as you would on your local machine. Simply copy the following two files to the Azure instance.

1. FUSLOGVW.exe
2. flogvwrc.dll

These files can be found on your local machine (if you've got the windows SDK installed) in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\1033

Obviously, some sections of that path will be dependent on your windows and .net versions.

As Jeremy said, any changes you make to the VM whilst RDPed, will be wiped off if you restart your service.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to hook into `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` - details on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx).

Technically it's feasible to run the full Fusion Log Viewer on the console on an Azure instance. You'd need to use Remote Desktop to access it, and reinstall it every time the instance is reimaged, so it's really only practical to do this when debugging a single instance.